# Арифметические выражения на bash

Tags: bash, математика

Можно ли на bash передать в качестве переменной арифметическое выражение с переменными? Пример:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Введите выражение"
read eq
read a
read b
let "r = `echo $eq`"
echo $r
```

В качестве тестирования ввожу такие данные, при запуске скрипта:

```
Введите выражение

2 * a + 3 * b
5
7
```

для каждого из read соответственно. Пробовал и иначе передавать выражение, например:

```
2 * $a + 3 * $b
```

В первом случае получаю ошибку вида:

```
./halfdiv.sh: line 6: let: r = 2 halfdiv.sh a + 3 halfdiv.sh b: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh a + 3 halfdiv.sh b")
```

Во втором:

```
./halfdiv.sh: line 6: let: r = 2 halfdiv.sh $a + 3 halfdiv.sh $b: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh $a + 3 halfdiv.sh $b")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно что-то делаю не так? И можно ли вообще реализовать это таким способом, как подразумеваю я?

Comment: Уравнение `echo  let "$eq"`. Результат `echo $(let "$eq")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас несколько многословно (да и ошибочно) выражено получение значения. достаточно так:

```
r=$(($eq))
```

---

работоспособный пример в виде однострочника:

```
$ eq="2 * a + 3 * b" a=5 b=7 r=$(($eq)); echo $r
31
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как можно оперировать таким образом с дробными числами? пробовал например так:
    r=$(bc -l <<< ($eq))
да и много других вариантов, но ничего не получилось

Comment: задайте лучше новый вопрос (кнопка «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы). комментарии не предназначены для вопросов/ответов.